# (bash) searching for specific file extensions in a fixed folder not working if the file name has a space

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script for my own needs, which I will search for only graphic files in a specific folder. Then I will perform a loop with actions on each of these files.
I have a problem because when the file name has a space it does not work (without spaces works fine).

```
for file in "/Users/user1/Documents/some folder"/*.jpg; do
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
for me the solution was move slash at the end of the directory path.
I modified a little bit my script and the working version is:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/Users/user1/Documents/some folder/"
fixedDate="07/21/2012" #mm/dd/yy
fileType="*.jpeg"

for file in "$dir"$fileType; do
    echo file:"$file"
    justTime=$(GetFileInfo -d "${file}" | cut -d ' ' -f2)
    echo justtime:$justTime
    newDate="$fixedDate "$justTime
    echo newDate:$newDate
    SetFile -d "$newDate" "${file}"
done
```

Comment: Make sure you quote the `$file` variable when you use it inside the loop.

Comment: Wrong slash at the end of the path. Should be:
for file in "/Users/user1/Documents/some folder/"*.jpg; do

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the slash is inside the quotes or not.

Comment: If you want to correct or clarify the question, click the "edit" link, don't put it in comments.

Comment: I'm new here. thanks for the clarification.